# MS BOT Framework: Attachments

Tags: node.js, bots

I am trying to work with attachments in the MS Bot Framework using the example from the site:

```js
function(session) {
  console.log('here')
  builder.Prompts.text(session, "Please upload the latest report now")
},
function(session, results) {
  console.log(session)
  var msg = session.message;
  if (msg.attachments && msg.attachments.length > 0) {
    // Echo back attachment
    var attachment = msg.attachments[0];
    session.send({
      text: "You sent:",
      attachments: [{
        contentType: attachment.contentType,
        contentUrl: attachment.contentUrl,
        name: attachment.name
      }]
    });
  } else {
    // Echo back users text
    session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
  }
}
```

This works when you enter text but not when you attach (via the option in the Bot Emulator) either an image or a spreadsheet.  I have no clue as to why this isn't working :(

EDIT 1: So when you add an image, the console logs

> / - Session.beginDialog(siteOwnerRefresh:/)
>
> .siteOwnerRefresh:/ - waterfall() step 1 of 2
>
> .siteOwnerRefresh:/ - Session.beginDialog(BotBuilder:prompt-text)
>
> ..BotBuilder:prompt-text - Session.send()
>
> ..BotBuilder:prompt-text - Session.sendBatch() sending 1 message(s)
>
> WARN: ChatConnector: receive - emulator running without security enabled.
>
> ChatConnector: message received.
>
> UniversalBot("*") routing 1 attachment(s) from "emulator"
>
> Library("BotBuilder").findRoutes() explanation:
>
> ActiveDialog(0.1)
>
> ..BotBuilder:prompt-text - WARN: Prompt - no intent handler found for null
>
> ..BotBuilder:prompt-text - Session.send()
>
> ..BotBuilder:prompt-text - Session.sendBatch() sending 1 message(s)

Comment: is there any error shown?

Comment: Try restarting the Bot Emulator. Sometimes this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the bot didn't work from with a second step of the cascade.  I moved it out it was the first step in the cascade and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

After builder.Prompts.text() it only receive a text message. 
Use **builder.Prompts.attachment** to receive a Attachment.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt